# How to connect from vSphere Client to ESXi? Ping from ESXi to Win fails

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualization, esxi, vsphere

I have Ubuntu 13.04 and VirtualBox installed. I created 2 virtual machines:

1. for ESXi
2. for Windows XP and vSphere Client

On my first VirtualBox virtual machine I installed an ESXi on my VirtualBox, gave it a static IP address of 192.168.0.4 set bridging network in VB network settings.

Then, I installed on my second VirtualBox virtual machine, where I have Windows XP installed, vSphere Client.

When Im on this Windows XP virtual machine and in the web browser type the address of 192.168.0.4 I can see a VMWare ESXi welcome page, so its ok I guess.

But when I try to connect to it with vSphereClient, I see such window:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Why cant I connect to ESXi?

Ping from my Windows on the second virtual machine to ESXi (on the first virtual machine, 192.168.0.4) works ...

IP of my Windows Xp on the second virtual machine is 192.168.0.5 so they're both in the same subnet.

When I try to ping Windows XP from ESXi, ping fails. When I turn off the firewall in Windows XP, ping from ESXi is ok but still cant connect from vSphere Client to ESXi ...

Also, I dont think that turning off the firewall is the best idea for doing this but without it, ping from ESXi to Win XP fails ...

Why? How to solve it?

Comment: @nos: I think you misunderstood me :) I have a VirtualBox and 2 virtual machines created with it. On the first machine I installed ESXi, on the second Windows XP and vSphere. On both virtual machines I set up bridging - as I wrote - ping is ok, so it works but still cant connect from vSphere

Comment: Can you check if your ESXi Server Management service is running ?

Comment: @user2196728: Im kind a new to these things, where can I check it? Ok, I think I restarted it: 1) Connect to the console of your ESXi host, 2)Press F2 to customize the system 3) Log in as root 4) Use the Up/Down arrows to navigate to Restart Management Agents.

Note: In ESXi 4.1 and ESXi 5.x, this option is available under Troubleshooting Options.

Comment: Connect to your ESXi using SSH and run "ps -ef | grep hostd | grep -v grep". You should have a process named "vmware-hostd"

Comment: @user2196728: I have only this: http://pastie.org/private/vx4ikuwm3ilm04ua1a6la when I did `ps -ef | grep hostd | grep -v grep`

Comment: Then, to be able to connect to your ESXi using VSphere, your Windows XP host has to be able to reach TCP port 902 of your ESXi. Try telnet 192.168.0.4 902 and check that your Windows firewall is not blocking it !

Comment: @user2196728: When I did `telnet 192.168.0.4 902` on my cmd on Windows XP I got this: `220 VMware Authentication Daemon Version 1.10: SSL Required, ServerDaemonProtocol:SOAP, MKSDisplayProtocol:VNC , VMXARGS supported, NFCSSL supported`

Comment: Are you running XP 32 or 64 bits ? Are you running at least SP2 ?

Comment: @user2196728: its 32-bit OS SP3, when I tried to connect from PuTTy on Windows XP to ESXi, it connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the comments, i suggest to have a look [here](http://www.mikelaverick.com/2013/10/vsphere-5-5-client-and-windowsxpwindows2003-unknown-connection-error/) and check if you are in this case.
If yes, i would suggest to use Windows7 instead of WinXP or use the VSphere Web Interface that should be at `https://192.168.0.4:9443`

Edit : i made a mistake, you cannot use the VSphere Web Interface. Only works against a VCenter server

Comment: Ok, will check the link in a while but when I tried to reach https://192.168.0.4:9443/ in my web browser it said that the page could not be loaded. Why? And another question: when I I have my firewall turned off ping from ESXi to Win XP fails. Ping from Win XP to ESXi works. I added exception ports: 902,903,389, 9443 into Windows XP firewall rules.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway :) But how about ping from ESXi, why it works only when I completly turn off the firewall?

Comment: Add a firewall rule to allow ping or ICMP

Comment: Worked! Cheers! Ok so I guess I should simply create another virtual machine with Windows XP SP3 64 bit or Windows 7, install vSphere Client and try again, right? ;) Take care

Comment: Right, install Win7 instead of XP again ;)